# Default TCP KeepAlive settings

Tags: networking, tcp, defaults

The TCP KeepAlive (socket option `SO_KEEPALIVE`) is governed by three options—time after which the mechanism triggers, probing interval, and number of failed probes after which the connecting is declared broken.

Their defaults are:

- tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
- tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
- tcp_keepalive_probes = 9

Sending probes after 1¼ minutes sound reasonable, and declaring failure after 9 failed probes does as well, but what is the idea behind the initial time being **2 hours**?

Even [tcp(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp) says

> Note that underlying connection tracking mechanisms and application timeouts may be much shorter.

The main point of enabling keepalive is to prevent any stateful network elements from dropping the state information, but such elements tend to drop the connections in a couple of *minutes*. With some rate-limited servers, `curl` with short `--keepalive-time` seems to significantly improve reliability of downloads.

So why is the default so long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TCP Keep-alive was defined at a time when even the concept of firewall, let alone stateful firewall or NAT, was probably not widespread. From [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101) (October 1989):

> 4.2.3.6  TCP Keep-Alives
>
> Implementors MAY include "keep-alives" in their TCP
> implementations, although this practice is not universally
> accepted.  If keep-alives are included, the application MUST
> be able to turn them on or off for each TCP connection, and
> they MUST default to off.
>
> Keep-alive packets MUST only be sent when no data or
> acknowledgement packets have been received for the
> connection within an interval.  This interval MUST be
> configurable and **MUST default to no less than two hours**.

[...]

The main idea at the time wasn't about stateful information lost:

> DISCUSSION:
> A "keep-alive" mechanism periodically probes the other
> end of a connection when the connection is otherwise
> idle, even when there is no data to be sent.  The TCP
> specification does not include a keep-alive mechanism
> because it could:  **(1) cause perfectly good connections
>
> to break during transient Internet failures; (2)
>
> consume unnecessary bandwidth ("if no one is using the
>
> connection, who cares if it is still good?"); and (3)
>
> cost money for an Internet path that charges for
>
> packets**.

[...]

> A TCP keep-alive mechanism should only be invoked in
> server applications that might otherwise hang
> indefinitely and consume resources unnecessarily if a
> client crashes or aborts a connection during a network
> failure.

I skimmed the updating RFCs, but couldn't fine mention of keep alives.

Comment: Whoever wrote the RFC clearly never noticed the pathological cases where TCP just slows itself to halt… the keepalive seems to help against it.